# Python Random Choice Returning Same Result in Every Loop Iteration

Tags: python, loops, random

Anyone know why when I run this code I get the same dictionary entry appended 100 times?

```
from random import choice

aliens = []
alien = {}

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'purple', 'brown', 'yellow', 'coral']
points = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
speeds = ['slow', 'medium', 'fast']

for i in range(1,101):
    alien['color'] = choice(colors)
    alien['points'] = choice(points)
    alien['speed'] = choice(speeds)
    aliens.append(alien)

print(aliens)
```

Comment: You really only have a single alien, which you are modifying each time you go through the loop. That alien retains the last value it had when the loop finishes, and each element in `aliens` points to that same object. Try putting `alien = {}` into the loop, at the top.

Comment: Chris, this worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary as well as the list is stored by the link and adding it to another list, you simply create a new link to the same dictionary. Just use `alien.copy()`.

```
from random import choice

aliens = []
alien = {}

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'purple', 'brown', 'yellow', 'coral']
points = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
speeds = ['slow', 'medium', 'fast']

for i in range(1,101):
    alien['color'] = choice(colors)
    alien['points'] = choice(points)
    alien['speed'] = choice(speeds)
    aliens.append(alien.copy())

print(aliens)
```